# How to Change String Representation of Sympy Symbol?

Tags: python, sympy

Is there a simple way to change the string representation of a SymPy Symbol?

Example:

```
rpj_g0x = sp.symbols('r_{pj/g0\\,x}')
```

This will give me a valid, nicely printed symbol representing the x-component of a position vector.

[image]

However, if I want to convert this to code at a later point, I can't without doing a variable substitution because `r_{pj/g0,x}` is not a valid variable name in python.

It would be nice if at the time of construction, you could pass in a string to use for string representations of the symbol. Is there any way to do this?

**UPDATE**

Behavior I get:

```
rpj_g0x = sp.symbols('r_{pj/g0\\,x}')
str(rpj_g0x) # --> 'r_{pj/g0,x}'
```

Behavior I would like to get:

```
rpj_g0x = sp.symbols('r_{pj/g0\\,x}', str_repr='r_pj_g0x')
str(rpj_g0x) # --> 'r_pj_g0x'
```

I don't believe a `str_repr` argument exists, but this is the behavior that I'm trying to get as the string representation of the symbol is now a valid python variable name.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking. Do you want to change the _string representation_ of `sp.symbols('r_{pj/g0\\,x}')`, or do something funky with the variable it's assigned to…?!

Comment: @deceze, I've updated the question with an example. I'm trying to change the string representation of the underlying symbol

Comment: OK, that's clearer. But why? Why do you want the string representation to be a valid variable name?

Comment: I'm converting my long sympy expressions into matlab source code.